# how is it possible to put a div over a jwplayer5 video?

Tags: javascript, overlay, jwplayer, wmode

The problem is that on IE the video jwplayer5 goes over everything, and my goal is the user to avoid to click over the video, to prevent PLAY/PAUSE effects.
i was suggested to put a div over the video, I did it, but on Internet Explorer (i'm checking 9) is not working.

any known working suggestions?

this is my video:

```
var video1 = jwplayer('vid1').setup({
            'flashplayer': 'html/js/jwplayer5/player.swf',
            'id': 'playerVid1',
            'width': VIDPLAYER_CTRL.BIGVIDEO_WIDTH,
            'height': VIDPLAYER_CTRL.BIGVIDEO_HEIGHT,
            'file': VIDPLAYER_MODEL.MAIN_VIDEO['path'],
            'provider': 'http',
            'startparam': 'start',
            'controlbar': 'bottom',
            'image': VIDPLAYER_MODEL.MAIN_VIDEO['path_img'],
            wmode: 'transparent',
            'skin': 'html/js/jwplayer5/videoSkin/videoSkin.xml'
});
```

and this is my div where video is:

```
<div id="area1" class="aree">
        <div id="vid1_cover1" class="cover1big"></div>
        <div id="vid1_cover2" class="cover2big"></div>
        <div id="vid1"></div>
</div>
```

and this is the css to create a overlay div OVER the video:

```
  div.cover1big{
     background-color: transparent;
     position: absolute;
     width: 601px;
     height: 335px;
     top:0px;
     left:0px;
     z-index: 999;
  }
  div.cover2big{
     background-color: transparent;
     position: absolute;
     width: 576px;
     height: 26px;
     top:335px;
     left:25px;
     z-index: 999;
  }
```

Comment: When you say it's not working in IE, are your transparent DIV elements not appearing above the video, or are they just not stopping the 'click' on the video?

Comment: div are transparent. the problem is that they don't stop the click (PLAY or PAUSE) on the jwplayer video

Comment: i need two divs on it because i've a skin for some operations on the video, then i need to cover the rest of the video, because i don't want the user click pause or play over the video.

Comment: Are you setting the z-index of the player? `#playerVid1 {z-index: 0}` Also, should wmode be in ticks? 'wmode' I'm not sure how strict jwplayer is.

Comment: set the z-index to zero. what do you mean with wmode being in ticks?

Comment: wmode should be set to transparent.

Answer (score 1):

I would put the DIV over using the JW5 JS Plugin SDK.

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw5/31166/building-javascript-plugins

There is a hello world example here which creates a div over the player and it works in both Flash and HTML5 modes.

Comment: I've a another question, is it possible maybe to put all over the video the controlbar? i mean, with the skin?

Comment: Maybe, but that would be much harder. I would try to copy our sample hello world plugin first. ;-)

Comment: i tested your link, it works (as the previous adopted solution of the overlays) but it's still not working on internet explorer, is it normal? i'm using jwplayer 5.7.1864

Comment: Going to need to send us a link as per our normal support route.

Comment: is there a link for jwplayer 5.8? i will have the last test, thanks

Comment: hi @ethan, can i ask your mail to write you, because of the software privacy. thank you